# Styling the layout of a content type

Tags: theming, nodes

I am using drupal 8 and I am trying to get the layout of my content type "jacuzzi" to go from this:
[image]

To this [image]

As you can see, I am using bootstrap. What do I have to change (css or tpl or something else?) to group the text fields and add the right classes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me know , In which field you defined this text  **prijis ** ....

Comment: field_price (number(decimal))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use node--(machine name of contenttype).html.twig to achieve this thing.

```
<div class = "col-md-6 someclass">{{ content.field_machinenameofimage }}</div>
<div class = "col-md-6 someclass">{{ content.field_machinenameofotherfields }}</div>
```

Replace the {{ content }} by the above code. And change the above code how you want to achieve.

Comment: okay no problem